# How to check whether auto save functionality working or not using selenium web driver?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am working on a project which contains forms having auto save functionality.
I know how to send data for the fields but i dont how to check whether these fields are auto saved or not.

This is what I have done :

```
public class Ca1GeneralInformation {
    private static WebElement element = null;
    //Quick facts
    public static WebElement ca1_companyName(WebDriver driver){
        element = driver.findElement(By.id("ca1_GEN_coName"));
        return element;
    }
    public static WebElement ca1_WebAdress(WebDriver driver){
        element = driver.findElement(By.id("ca1_GEN_coURL"));
        return element;
    }
    public static WebElement ca1_YearFounded(WebDriver driver){
        element = driver.findElement(By.id("ca1_GEN_foundedDate"));
        return element;
    }
    public static WebElement ca1_nameOfCeo(WebDriver driver){
        element = driver.findElement(By.id("ca1_GEN_CEOname"));
        return element;
    }
    public static WebElement ca1_titleOfCeo(WebDriver driver){
        element = driver.findElement(By.id("ca1_GEN_CEOtitle"));
        return element;
    }
    public static WebElement ca1_becomeCeo(WebDriver driver){
        element = driver.findElement(By.id("ca1_GEN_CEOstart"));
        return element;
    }
    public static WebElement ca1_CeoJoinYear(WebDriver driver){
        element = driver.findElement(By.id("ca1_GEN_CEOjoin"));
        return element;
    }
    public static WebElement ca1_CeoFirstPosition(WebDriver driver){
        element = driver.findElement(By.id("ca1_GEN_CEOposition"));
        return element;
    }
}enter code here

//Send data for quick facts page
        Ca1GeneralInformation.ca1_companyName(driver).clear();
        Ca1GeneralInformation.ca1_companyName(driver).sendKeys("Test Company");
        Ca1GeneralInformation.ca1_WebAdress(driver).clear();
        Ca1GeneralInformation.ca1_WebAdress(driver).sendKeys("www.test.com");
        Ca1GeneralInformation.ca1_YearFounded(driver).clear();
        Ca1GeneralInformation.ca1_YearFounded(driver).sendKeys("2000");
        Ca1GeneralInformation.ca1_nameOfCeo(driver).clear();
        Ca1GeneralInformation.ca1_nameOfCeo(driver).sendKeys("mr.CEO");
        Ca1GeneralInformation.ca1_titleOfCeo(driver).clear();
        Ca1GeneralInformation.ca1_titleOfCeo(driver).sendKeys("CEO");
        Ca1GeneralInformation.ca1_becomeCeo(driver).clear();
        Ca1GeneralInformation.ca1_becomeCeo(driver).sendKeys("2002");
        Ca1GeneralInformation.ca1_CeoJoinYear(driver).clear();
        Ca1GeneralInformation.ca1_CeoJoinYear(driver).sendKeys("2001");
        Ca1GeneralInformation.ca1_CeoFirstPosition(driver).clear();
        Ca1GeneralInformation.ca1_CeoFirstPosition(driver).sendKeys("manager");
        driver.close();

>

`
```

Comment: Can you please explain what is auto save functionality for forms?

Comment: If I navigate from current form to the other form or refreshed the page without clicking submit button data on the old form remains as it is.

Answer (score 0):

In a similar case in our application - when you enter some text for the input field and click outside, the data is saved on db and is also displayed on the input field. (We fire one Ajax event-on blur to update our db) So you can try these:

- Connect to the DB and check for the update for the appropriate table
- Enter your test data on the input field/form and do the event which is in your case (like on blur - click outside on our case) and wait for few secs. You can do gettext() on the same field to validate if the value is stored or not.